# FastReport export to image in multipage reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, report, fastreport

I want to export a multi page report (FastReport) to image

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
rpt.Export(new ImageExport(), result);
```

reports with one page is OK, but multipage reports have this error :

> empty path name is not legal

Have any idea to solve this?!

Comment: what is the variable `result`? It's stream or file name?

Comment: @kmatyaszek It's stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use path, instead of stream.

Example with path:

```
using (FastReport.Report report = new FastReport.Report())
{
    report.Load(@"C:\test.frx");

    report.Prepare();                               
    report.Export(new FastReport.Export.Image.ImageExport(), "myReport.png");             
}
```

When report has more than one page, the following files will be created:

```
myReport.png
myReport.2.png
myReport.3.png
...
```

Here is solution with stream. You should set `PageRange = PageRange.Current` and set `CurPage` to appropriate value:

```
int count = 1;
using (FastReport.Report report = new FastReport.Report())
{
    report.Load(@"C:\test.frx");
    report.Prepare();

    foreach (PageBase item in report.Pages)
    {
        string fileName = string.Format("myReport_{0}.png", count);
        report.Export(new FastReport.Export.Image.ImageExport() { PageRange = PageRange.Current, CurPage = count }, fileName);
        count++;
    }
}
```